# Kafka Spout read twice message on Storm Topology

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, apache-storm

I'm trying to simulate stream traffic using Kafka to Storm. I used KafkaSpout to read a message from one topic sent by a Producer that read these Tweets and send them to a topic. My problem is that after topology consumes all tweet send in this topic it continues to read the message in the topic twice. How can I stop KafkaSpout from reading twice?(replication factor is set to 1)

Comment: Before anything else, please make sure you're using the latest Storm version. If it still doesn't work, please post your topology configuration (topology wiring, maybe also pom.xml).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edit my post with these information.

Comment: Could you post your spout configuration as well? Noticed a few other things you might want to change: The scope of storm-core should be "provided", not "compile". In Classifier.execute you can end up acking the tuple twice if an exception happens. You need to make sure only to ack the tuple exactly once, or Storm will consider it failed and replay it. Finally consider upgrading to `storm-kafka-client` as well as a new Kafka version. 0.8.2.2 is very old, and `storm-kafka` is deprecated for removal.

Comment: Ok thank you i think one of error is twice acking! I tried to migrate to storm-kafka-client but seems that it can't read data from topic. I update my first post with kafkaSpoutCreator and it's configuration. Really thank u for these help i'm actually a newbie of these framework.

Comment: Yes, it can't read the data because Kafka is too old. `storm-kafka-client` requires Kafka 0.10.1.0 (as far as I recall). But you can keep using `storm-kafka` if you want, just wanted to make sure you knew it will be deleted as of Storm 2.0.0. `storm-kafka` also isn't compatible with Kafka after version 2.0.0.

Comment: Actually I'm using the latest version of Apache Kafka(kafka_2.12-2.2.0) but it worked fine with storm-kafka until these error eheheh. I've updated my project inserting 
builder.setSpout("kafka_spout", new KafkaSpout<>(KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("127.0.0.1:9092", "tweet").build()), 1); 

but it doesn't read from Kafka stream.

Comment: Okay, that's surprising. That could also be the issue, as you're using client code with Kafka 2.x that is deprecated. The change is good. Please also remember to bump the `kafka-clients` version in your pom. You should also be able to remove the `kafka_2.9.2` dependency. Finally you might want to be aware of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3102, until Storm 1.2.3 (which we expect to be released shortly) there's a performance issue with Kafka 2.0.0.

Comment: It throws me 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.

Comment: You need to call `setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "your-group-name-here")` on the `KafkaSpoutConfig`. See also https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutTopologyMainNamedTopics.java for a complete example.

Comment: ok i'll try to set this new spout. It seems more complicated than previous one. No compile error in project but i can't actually test if problem is solved or not. I will update this topic with updates thank you! You really have improved my day!

Comment: Happy to help, hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration looks fine to me.

Maybe the issue is double acking. Make sure you're only acking each tuple once in `execute`.

As mentioned in a comment, please consider upgrading to a newer Kafka version, as well as switching to `storm-kafka-client`.

Also something that may make your life a little easier: Consider extending `BaseBasicBolt` instead of `BaseRichBolt`. `BaseBasicBolt` automatically acks the tuple for you if running `execute` doesn't throw an error. If you want to fail a tuple you can throw `FailedException`. `BaseRichBolt` should only be used if you want to do more complicated acking, e.g. aggregating tuples from many `execute` invocations in-memory before acking.

Comment: I noticed that consuming speed is drastically reduced by 4x! It's more slowly than previuous one. Is there any specific option to retrive message faster?

Comment: Quoting myself from above: "Finally you might want to be aware of issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3102, until Storm 1.2.3 (which we expect to be released shortly) there's a performance issue with Kafka 2.0.0". You need to upgrade to `storm-kafka-client` 1.2.3. If you don't want to wait for release, you can either download and build Storm yourself, or get the jar at https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachestorm-1081/org/apache/storm/storm-kafka-client/1.2.3/

Comment: Sorry i you have to post twice your answer. I tried to download and put jar into my intellij project jar but i get an exception of
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Supplier
when i start topology

Comment: What you want to do instead is to set the version of `storm-kafka-client` in your POM to 1.2.3. Then download the "org" directory at https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachestorm-1081/ and put it in your local Maven repository (most likely in your user dir `~/.m2/repository`). This should let IntelliJ/Maven pick the jars up.

Comment: You can also just add the https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachestorm-1081 URL as a repository to your POM as described at https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html, which may be easier.

Comment: Everything is working fine know(really thank you) except the first error that i described above in first post. It seems there are duplicated or two times analyzed tuple. I updated to BaseBasicBolt and removed ack and it has been reduced but still exists (for example i have 600k of tweets json tuple produced and at the end i find 650k tweets)

Comment: I would look for retries. Maybe some of your tuples are timing out and being retried. Try implementing one of these https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.3/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaTupleListener.java. You can add it to the KafkaSpoutConfig. Implement the onRetry method to log something. If that message is logged when you run, some tuple has failed and is being replayed.

Comment: Can you please explain me how? I'm using configuration from example provided by Storm(i'll edit first post because too long) to read from kafka stream.

Comment: Create a new class implementing the interface I linked. Make the onRetry method in that class log a message when it is called. Then create a new instance of that class, and register it in the KafkaSpoutConfig by calling this method https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.3/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig.java#L600.

Comment: Ok everything seeems to work fine. I'm running my topologies in localmode and actually it reach a max size analyzing 1 millions tuple (after that process only 1000 tuples every 10 minutes) so i think i've to process on a cluster.

Comment: As you said onRetry method shows that some tuple fail to be processed and are processed twice. How can i stop this behavior?

Comment: It depends on what you want to have happen. If it's due to timeout, you can cap how many tuples Storm will try processing at a time. See https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/docs/Performance.md#5-maxspoutpending. You set it in the Config object you pass to StormSubmitter. Then you should avoid timeouts and will only get duplicates if a tuple actually fails processing.

Comment: If on the other hand you want to not retry tuples on failure (and will accept some potential for message loss), you can use https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.3/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig.java#L171 in your KafkaSpoutConfig.

Comment: Ok i solved my problem with this settings. Really, really thank you. I'll insert you in my thanks of thesis :D